# Is it possible to overwrite default mapping of CsvHelper for a specific column, if a field under it is an empty string - to write something else?

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, .net-core, csvhelper

If we have a csv file with lots of columns, one of which is `HelloWorld`, is there a way to make it so that when `CsvHelper` parses the file, if the field under the column `HelloWorld` is empty, instead of returning/writing an empty string, to write something else (for example `null`, or `hello!`).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use the `ClassMap` or `CsvClassMap` it depends on which version are you using. `ClassMap` is the latest implementation. Here is an example for the HelloWorld column:

```
sealed class HelloWorldDefinitionMap : ClassMap<HelloWorldRow>
{
    public HelloWorldDefinitionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.HelloWorld).Default("empty");
    }
}
```